# Mouse wheel scrolling inserts characters

Tags: macvim, tmux, iterm2

I'm using macvim inside tmux inside iTerm2. Basically I just want to be able to scroll the buffer using the mousewheel. I've set

```
set -g moude-mouse on
```

in my `.tmux.conf`, and

```
set mouse=a
set ttymouse=xterm2
```

in my `.vimrc`. Additionally I enabled 'xterm mouse reporting' in iTerm2.

Whenever I use the mouse wheel, vim will switch to insert mode and insert seemingly random characters. I'm guessing vim can't correctly interpret the mouse escape-codes.

The problem also appears outside of tmux and in the default Terminal.app which leads me to believe that it's a vim issue.

I've expiremented with all possible values of `ttymouse`, none had the desired effect.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Ah, I found the culprit by bisecting my `.vimrc` file. I had mapped <kbd>Escape</kbd> in normal mode to clear search highlighting:

```
" Clear highlighting on escape in normal mode
nnoremap <esc> :noh<return><esc>
```

However, that will confuse vim as it tries to parse the mouse's escape codes. So what I ended up doing is taking the solution from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1037182/337591), and also mapping:

```
" needed so that vim still understands escape sequences
nnoremap <esc>^[ <esc>^[
```

Which will fix that issue.

Comment: this saved me from a lot of pain -- deserves to be in vim docs or somewhere prominent.